# Certaines combinaisons de pronoms seraient interdites ?

Tags: pronoms, linguistique

Pierre rencontre Jacques.

> — Comment s'est passée ta réunion ?
>     — Nous avons décidé qu'il nous fallait un représentant expérimenté.
>     — Et vous t'avez donc choisi ?

Ouch. À n'en pas douter vos oreilles sifflent tout autant que les miennes.
Si ce n'était pour l'exemple nous ne me le pardonnerions certainement pas (oui, j'en rajoute) !

D'où vient donc le mal ? Quel hasard nous empêche-t-il de formuler de telles phrases dans un contexte où « vous » et « toi » (respectivement « nous » et « moi ») renvoient à des personnes parfaitement déterminées ?

Quelle loi du langage aurait condamné les unions « vous te » et « nous me » ?

Comment: Question pertinente, car c'est vrai que cette structure n'aurait *a priori* rien de choquant. J'ai souvenir de l'avoir entendu parfois (rarement), mais précisément pour invoquer ce sentiment d'étrangeté que tu décris, presque toujours pour adopter un ton plaisant ou comique. (En revanche, je n'ai pas saisi le lien avec l'inceste... c'est un contraste entre un pronom pluriel avec pronom singulier mais quel rapport ?)

Comment: Je pense que c'est plutôt « vous l'avez choisi », non ?
Sinon, non, je ne vois rien de choquant ici. La réunion s'étant faite à plusieurs, elle peut donc aisément renvoyer à l'ensemble des personnes présentes à cette dernière. De plus, certaines personnes vouvoient toujours, d'autres tutoient plus facilement, ce qui peut parfois créer un décalage. On peut rajouter à cela, que parmi celles qui vouvoient autrement que par politesse, certaines familles le font même entre elles, question d'éducation (entre famille "artiso/chrétienne" souvent).

Comment: @Laure : même première réflexion, mais rien ne choquerait avec « vous **m**'avez donc choisi ? », l'usage voudrait : « ils t'ont donc choisi ? », alors que ce sont les personnes du même dialogue

Comment: @Larme: Ce qui est choquant c'est « vous te ». Par comparaison aucun problème ne se poserait si l'on souhaitait dire « tu t'es choisi », ou si l'on omet la personne elle-même : « ils t'ont choisi » ou « tes collègues t'ont choisi ».

Comment: En quoi « nous me » ou « vous te » seraient-ils choquants ou illicites ? As-tu trouvé cette affirmation dans une grammaire ?

Comment: @Gilles: Je ne pensais pas avoir à me justifier ! Je te mets au défi de l'utiliser dans une conversation normale. À part ça je viens de me rendre compte que mon correcteur orthographique refuse « t'avez » ou « m'avons », et ce sont les deux seules configurations qu'il refuse.

Comment: @Romain: Je constatais que certaines unions étaient inconcevables ; je viens de changer le titre.

Comment: Je partage ta réticence. Je viens de passer un certain temps à en chercher mention dans Grevisse sans rien trouver de pertinent.

Comment: *Nous m'avons élue à l'unanimité*. Il me semble bien l'avoir déjà dit, certes, mon correcteur orthographique le souligne, (enfin celui a fait le programme lui a dit de le souligner) mais ça ne me choque absolument pas. Comment pourrais-je dire autrement de façon concise que je fais partie des votants qui m'ont élue ?

Comment: @Laure: J'admets qu'il y a de rares cas (comme celui que tu cites) dans lesquels « nous me » ne m'interpelle que légèrement. « Vous te » en revanche, je ne vois pas comment le placer.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez et moi j'admets ne jamais avoir entendu « vous te » !

Comment: Aucune règle ne dit que c'est faux, seul l'usage semble rare.

Comment: Usage rare = ça veut dire que ça existe. A toi de prouver que l'usage est rare. Tu demandes toujours aux autres de prouver, mais là c'est ton tour. Si tu trouves UN SEUL écrivain classique qui utiise cette tournure (par ailleurs illogique), je me rangerais de ton avis.Pour le reste, je suis d'accord avec Stéphane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il semble bien qu'aucune règle grammaticale n'interdise les combinaisons évoquées.

Si « **vous t'avez choisi** » surprend, ce n'est à priori que pour des raisons sémantiques.

Source : [MANUEL DE LA GRAMMAIRE FRANÇAISE Gabriel Wyler](https://web.archive.org/web/20190316202531/http://gabrielwyler.com/page179.html) (archived) :

> Les règles de base des formes conjointes - phénomènes mineurs
>
> ¶ Limitations extragrammaticales
>
> § Limitations sémantiques
>
> Il y a quatre groupes de pronoms personnels conjoints qui sont grammaticalement impeccables, mais sémantiquement bizarres. Ils n'écorchent pas les oreilles, mais ils ne correspondent à aucun besoin pratique de communication.
>
> - nous me le disons
> - vous te le dites
> - je nous le dis
> - tu vous le dis

L'absence de besoin pratique est contestable. Il est par exemple tout à fait possible de dire :

> C'est **moi** que **nous** avons choisi.
> C'est **toi** que **vous** avez choisi.

qui sont essentiellement équivalents à :

> **Nous m'avons** choisi.
> **Vous t'avez** choisi.

Lorsqu'un élu est lui-même électeur de l'élection qu'il a gagnée, rien ne devrait l'empêcher (sauf la modestie) de dire ***Nous m'avons élu*** au lieu des plus traditionnels ***Vous m'avez élu*** et ***On m'a élu***. Dans cette dernière forme, ***on*** peut avoir la valeur de n'importe quelle personne du pluriel (***nous, vous, ils/elles***).

Answer (score 3):

La forme est considérée comme incorrecte par certains grammairiens:
http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=VnFWgqu54ooC , "jeux du singulier et du pluriel"

Cependant, il ne s'agit certainement pas d'une règle élémentaire, et en linguistique, l'usage triomphe... donc ne vous gênez pas!

Je pense que la bizarrerie vient de 2 éléments :

- une inhibition qui arrive lorsque nous apprenons la forme polie avec des verbes réfléchis :

> enfant: Vous t'appelez comment?
>
> parent: Non, vous **vous** appelez comment!

- la plupart des actions incluent un actif et un passif, mais ici le passif fait partie du groupe des actifs, ce qui est un cas excessivement rare.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a effectivement des combinaisons impossibles (et inattestées) pour les pronoms dits clitiques mais elles concernent plutôt des combinaisons comme me, te, nous, vous, se et lui/leur.

> Paul n'a pas voulu me présenter à Julie.
>   *Paul n'a pas voulu me lui présenter.
>
> La secrétaire n'a pas voulu me la passer.
>   *Ta secrétaire n'a pas voulu me te passer.
>   ...

Comment: Effectivement, il y a aussi des clashs entre pronoms objet direct et indirect !

Comment: Je ne comprends pas le sens de "me lui présenter". ça donnerait quoi non raccourci par des pronoms? Me le présenter = Paul n'a pas voulu me présenter X. Mais me lui présenter? "lui" ça désigne qui? Je ne vois que Paul n'a pas voulu me le présenter -> dans ce cas, ça marche. Paul n'a pas voulu lui présenter: je ne sais pas non plus ce que ça signifie.

Comment: Pour la première question, j'ai ajouté un exemple dans le corps de la réponse. Pour la remarque sur *me te*, il semble qu'il y ait une confusion entre deux cas : *me* et *te* sont tous les deux ambigus entre pronom direct (ACC) et indirect (DAT) : *je te(ACC) vois* vs *je te(DAT) parle*...

Comment: "me" et "te" selon la règle de la place des pronoms, doivent tous les 2 arriver en première position, on n'aura aucun pronom devant "me" et aucun devant "te". Ils deviennent forcément des prénoms disjoints quand c'est le cas.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ça, c'est si on ne tient pas compte des pronoms clitiques sujet (*je/tu/il/on/ils*). Effectivement, un seul pronom de [position 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#Clitic_order) est permis avec une fonction ACC/DAT. Bien sûr *me* et *te* peuvent apparaître ensemble si le premier est un [datif éthique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/datif_%C3%A9thique) : *il te m'a mis une de ces baffes!*

Comment: C'est plus de la grammaire descriptive dans ce cas, car je doute que cet usage soit grammaticalement correct, mais c'est amusant de voir qu'on utilise ce terme pour décrire cette tournure argotique. Je ne connaissais pas! Tu as d'autres liens sur ce genre de description de l'argot, et au sujet du datif éthique?

Answer (score 0):

Elle me te montre est impossible probablement à cause du sens:

me + te = nous     = à moi et à toi

On peut donc avoir:

Elle me montre (= à moi).

Elle te montre (= à toi).

Elle nous montre (= à nous = à moi et à toi  ou à moi et à eux ou à moi, à toi et à eux) ambiguïté qui ne peut être levée que par le contexte.

Answer (score 0):

Vous t'aimez est impossible.

*Si on a un vous de politesse, il faut utiliser le vous complément 'vous vous aimez (vous-même) pour ne pas mélanger la forme de politesse et la forme familière qui serait 'Tu t'aimes (toi-même)'. Avec vous pluriel on aurait: Vous vous aimez (vous-mêmes) Cas réfléchi.

*On peut aussi avoir le sens réciproque: 'vous vous aimez (l'un l'autre).
S'il s'agit d'un 'vous' concernant plus de deux personnes on aura alors le sens de 'vous vous aimez (les uns les autres)'.

- Si le sens n'est ni réfléchi ni réciproque. Il faut choisir à qui l'on s'adresse, même en présence du ou des autres. On ne peut s'adresser à 'vous' ou à 'toi' en même temps, 'tu' faisant partie du 'vous' pluriel.

'Vous l'aimez (lui ou elle)' ou 'Il / elle t'aime (toi)' ou Ils ou elles t'aiment.

Comment: Vous PL et Tu SG n'est pas paradoxal. On en trouve *Tu vous a évité des ennuis*. Ce qui semble problématique, c'est le Vous PL sujet et le TE obj SG...

Comment: Pour moi 'tu vous a évité des ennuis' n'est absolument pas français; par contre 'Tu nous a évité des ennuis' est tout à fait correct. (I am a native French speaker)

Answer (score 0):

'nous me' ne s'utilise pas puisque 'me' est déjà inclus dans nous.

On ne dit pas: Nous m'avons choisi. mais On m'a choisi, J'ai été choisi.

Comme l'information importante est le résultat du choix, il peut être mis en vedette au début de la phrase:

J'ai été choisi.

C'est moi que l'on a choisi. C'est moi qu'on a choisi.

C'est moi que nous avons choisi.

C'est moi qui ai été choisi.

Answer (score 0):

'Et vous t'avez choisi' est bien sûr impossible puisque dans le cas où il s'agit d'un vous désignant plusieurs personnes on aurait:

vous (= toi + eux) te (= le même toi) avez choisi (= avaient choisi).

Dans la phrase impossible le 'te' complément fait déjà partie de l'ensemble des personnes sujets désignées par 'vous'.

La phrase impossible serait alors un mélange de deux phrases dont la deuxième seule serait à la forme réfléchie et la première à la forme non réfléchie:
Vous l'avez choisi (forme non réfléchie) + Tu t'es choisi (forme réfléchie)

Remarque: la forme réfléchie entraîne obligatoirement l'emploi de l'opérateur être (orientation subjective: à gauche) or l'exemple impossible utilise comme dans la forme non réfléchie de cet exemple l'opérateur avoir (orientation  vers le verbe: à droite). Autre raison de l'impossibilité.

Dans vous l'avez choisi. L'attention porte sur 'choisi' donc opérateur 'avoir'.

Dans Tu t'es choisi(e). L'attention est portée sur 'Tu te' donc opérateur 'être'.

Answer (score -1):

Paul n'a pas voulu me présenter à Julie. ou me présenter à elle.

'Présenter à' sert à introduire le nom Julie (choisi parmi d'autres possibles) qui peut être remplacé par le pronom elle, pour insister sur le fait que c'est bien de Julie que l'on choisit de parler, c'est comme une répétition insistante lorsque le nom de Julie se trouve déjà dans le contexte avant.

Paul n'a pas voulu me présenter Jacques.

Le prénom Jacques est choisi parmi d'autres possibles. Je présente mon choix.

Paul n'a pas voulu me LE présenter. LE remplace le nom Jacques, nom déjà choisi dans le contexte avant. LE se place pour cette raison avant 'présenter'.

Ton secrétaire n'a pas voulue me passer Jane. Ici on présente le nom choisi: il arrive après 'passer'

Ton secrétaire n'a pas voulu me la passer (elle).  'la' remplace 'elle' qui reste sous-entendu sauf pour lourdement insister. 'la' est placé avant 'passer' parce que l'on a dépassé le moment de la présentation de ce dont on parle: Jane.

le, la formes faibles; lui, elle formes fortes

Marie n'a pas voulu me LE présenter (LUI). (lui =Jacques)

Ton secrétaire n'a pas voulu me LA passer (ELLE). (elle = Jane)

Comment: Je ne vois absolument pas le rapport avec la question.

Comment: Peut-être que c'était une réponse à une autre question?

Comment: Oui, il manque l'étude du cas des doubles pronoms.

Answer (score -1):

**Règles des doubles pronoms**

- On ne peut pas en français utiliser la forme "vous te" + verbe, pour des raisons de logique. *Vous t'aimez*. N'est pas la logique utilisée par le français.

Apparemment en français, on ne peut pas avoir une personne collective, qui se sépare du collectif, et agit au nom d'une personne individuelle.

"Vous t'aimez" et "Nous m'avons voulu" n'est donc pas dans la logique de la langue.

Pour que deux pronoms se suivent on doit avoir, en général:

- Cas des pronoms réflexifs: **nous nous** sommes mis à chanter, **nous nous** lavons, etc...
  Nous vous lavons. (si ce n'est pas réflexif)
- Les deux pronoms ne sont pas au même "cas" grammatical. L'un est un **pronom direct**, et l'autres est un **pronom indirect**. On peut avoir aussi un **pronom joint** et un **pronom disjoint**.

La difficulté arrive quand les deux pronoms sont conjoints.

*Rappel de grammaire*: *un pronom conjoint est un pronom qui est entre le sujet et le verbe, et un pronom disjoint sera séparé par une proposition*.

Quand les deux pronoms sont en concurrence, il y forcément un qui *fait* l'action (pronom personnel sujet),un qui *reçoit* l'action, et un qui *est sujet de* l'action. Il y a donc **3 cas grammaticaux**, et on ne peut pas utiliser le même cas pour deux d'entre eux.

Mais il arrive que la forme COI (que j'appelle "cas", comme en latin) et la forme COD soit la même. Il y a ambiguïté. On ne sait pas quel est le pronom qui reçoit l'action, et celui qui en est l'objet.

C'est pour ça qu'il y a, pour éviter ce genre d’ambiguïté, des règles applicables aux pronoms conjoints.

Par exemple "me te" est impossible si on suit les 2 règles fondamentales.

Pour éviter de suivre ces règles, il est facile de transformer le pronom conjoint en pronom disjoint, sur le modèle Elle me parle (conjoint) -> Elle parle à moi (disjoint)

**Les règles des pronoms conjoints sont:**

- Une règle pour *l'ordre* des pronoms.
- **Et une règle pour éviter l’ambiguïté du cas du pronom**

En combinant ces deux règles, on arrive à des cas impossibles, selon que l'une ou l'autre ait été violée.

Très bien expliqué ici: http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html

Par exemple, selon la règle des pronoms conjoints, "te" dois obligatoirement apparaître en première position, et **jamais en seconde**.

> Je **te** dis.

Mais on aura jamais:

> Je me **te** + verbe.

Me et te sont en concurrence pour la première position...

[Is “Elle me te montre” correct?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16756/is-elle-me-te-montre-correct)

--

On remarque aussi qu'il y a une ambiguïté dans "Elle **me** passe", si pas de contexte.

> Elle me passe.
>   Elle me passe à quelqu'un.
>   Elle me passe à lui.

L'objet passé est "me" et le destinataire est "quelqu'un".

> Elle me passe.
>   Elle me passe Féodor.
>   Elle **me** le passe.
>   Elle le passe *à moi*.

L'objet passé est "Féodor" et le destinataire est "me".

Dans l'exemple donné, *elle me te passe*. On aurait "te" comme objet passé, et "me" comme destinataire. C'est le "te" qui n'est pas au bon cas. Elle te passe à moi.

**Pronoms disjoints COI**
me: Elle me raconte
te: Elle te raconte
lui (masculin): Elle lui raconte
lui (féminin): Elle lui raconte.
nous: Elle nous raconte.
vous: Elle vous raconte.
leur: (masculin et neutre): Elle leur raconte.
leur: (féminin): Elle leur raconte.

**Pronoms conjoints COD**
me: elle me voit
te: elle te voit
le: elle le voit
la: elle la voit
nous: elle nous voit
vous: elle vous voit
les: elle les voit
les elle les voit

**Pronoms disjoint**, pour dire que l'action est dirigé vers quelqu'un
moi, à moi
toi, à toi etc...

**Liste complète des combinaisons possibles de pronoms**
(sous réserve d'étourderies of course)

**Avec me:**

me le/me la
me les

**Avec le/la:**

le lui/la lui
le leur/la leur

**Avec te:**

te le/te la
te les

**Avec se:**

se le/se la
se les

**Avec les:**

les la/les lui
les leur
les vous/les nous

**Avec nous/vous:**

nous le/nous la/vous le/vous la
nous les/vous les
nous leur/vous leur

**Les pronoms qui doivent toujours se trouver en première position:**

> me, te, se nous, vous

(Bien sûr, j'éditerais si j'en ai oublié, mais obligée de préciser, pour éviter de se faire agresser ici)

> Tu nous le dit

et pas

> Tu le nous dit

(ne pas confondre le "nous" et le "vous" du sujet)

**Les pronoms qu'on peut mettre en deuxième position:**

> la, les, lui, leur,

Comment: De toutes ces règles, laquelle expliquerait que *"vous t'avez choisi"* ou *"nous m'avons désigné"* seraient faux ?

Comment: "Vous t'avez" est pourtant expliqué au tout début, et pour "nous me", j'ai oublié de le mentionner, mais c'est le même principe!

Comment: C'est bien ce que je pensais.

Comment: Voilà, j'ai développé. "logique" ne voulait pas dire grand chose, pas expliqué.

Comment: Merci, et c'est ton ressenti personnel ou une règle ? Je suis d'accord qu'une telle utilisation interroge, mais si aucune règle grammaticale ne dit explicitement que c'est interdit, alors on peut imaginer des cas dans lesquels ça fait sens.

Comment: Pourquoi imaginer? Trouves-en. Si c'est une règle, elle doit avoir des contre-exemples. Une langue n'est pas faite que de règles écrites, elle est aussi faite de "logiques" et d'habitudes. Il y a des choses que les anglais par exemple disent d'une certaine façon, et qu'on dira plutôt d'une autre, et pourtant, il n'y a pas de règles qui l'interdisent. ça va plus loin que les règles l'usage. La règle est simplement: ce sont 2 pronoms incompatibles (voir fin de l'explication), mais il est bien possible qu'il ait une logique derrière cette règle.

Comment: Je te demande si c'est une règle ou non. Si ce n'est pas une règle mais juste un ressenti dû à la rareté, alors rien ne rend faux une phrase comme *"Nous m'avons désignée comme la représentante de cette classe"* si la personne qui parle fait partie du groupe de personnes qui l'a désignée.

Comment: Lis tout. Ce sont 2 pronoms incompatibles = c'est une règle. Va voir la liste des pronoms incompatibles.

Comment: J'ai évidemment lu en entier, et je ne vois pas où est la contre-indication. *Nous désignons moi* = *Nous me désignons*, *me* est un COD en première position après le sujet, c'est le cas le plus basique possible, si ce n'est ce problème d'accroche à l'oreille dû à une rareté d'utilisation.

Comment: Quand une forme est inexistante, ce n'est pas un problème d'oreille, ni de rareté, ces pronoms ne sont pas compatibles, tu ne les trouveras jamais dans aucun manuel de conjugaison, où tu as pourtant toute la liste des "je te", "je me"... Je te le répète, cette association est listée comme "interdite". Une chose rare est rare mais existe, là tu auras beaucoup de mal à trouver dans des livres, dans des journaux, cette forme qui n'est tout simplement jamais employée.

Comment: A moins que je me trompe, et que tu nous trouves des exemples. Même sans être interdite, quand une chose n'est jamais jamais employée, elle est de fait incorrecte.

Comment: [Les ombres claires](http://ombresclaires.tumblr.com/post/144258070203/goutte) : *Nous m'avons déçu.* [L'expédition H.G. Wells](https://goo.gl/cJchLO) : *Nous ne m'avons rien expliqué.*

Comment: Un écrivain, pas un livre avec des légendes sous des photos. http://www.bdnet.com/catalogue_detail_Les-Ombres-Claires--9782372450089