# Combinaisons de pronoms interdites ?

Tags: pronoms-personnels

J'apprends l'ordre des pronoms personnels et il semble qu'il y a des combinaisons incompatibles. Mais je ne trouve pas de bonne explication.

Considérez la phrase anglaise: « I gave you to them » ou alternativement (mais gauche) « I gave them you ».

Si je la traduis, j'obtiendrais: « Je te leur ai donné ». Dans cette construction, j'utilise *te* en tant qu'objet direct et *leur* en tant qu'objet indirect. Mais je n'ai jamais vu la construction « je te leur ... » et [cet article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#Clitic_order) suggère que cette combinaison est interdite.

Comment: to give someone to someone is not necessarily donner. It can be: livrer. Anyway, I gave the child to the parents: **I gave her to them**. Je l'ai donné à eux.  enfant. I gave them to you. [object] Je te les ai donnéés. [lunettes]. Tout dépend du contexte.

Comment: Que signifie *I gave you to them* ?

Comment: Il ne faut pas essayer de traduire comme ça avant de comprendre comment ça marche. Vous ne pouvez pas arriver à apprendre les verbes en anglais de cette façon.

Comment: I gave you to them, peut vouloir signifier: When you were a baby, I gave you to them [those people]. It can also mean livrer, as in livrer à l'ennemi.

Comment: I gave you to them. is **as weird in English as it is French**: Je te leur ai donné. Un bébé pas voulu? Une esclave? Un proxenète parlant de sa prostituée?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On peut traduire ***I gave you to them*** (littéralement: ***j'ai donné toi à eux***) par ***je t'ai donné(e) à eux*** ou éventuellement le très relâché ***Je leur ai donné toi***.

Je n'ai jamais entendu la combinaison *je te leur ai donné* avec ce sens où elle est effectivement inusitée.

Elle se rencontre cependant en français très relâché mais avec un autre sens et requiers dans ce cas un complément d'objet direct placé après le verbe, par exemple :

> Je te leur ai donné une de ces leçons !

La phrase signifie *Je leur ai donné une de ces leçons !* et le pronom *te* sert [à inviter l'interlocuteur à porter attention à l'action exprimée par le verbe](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2927) (BDL, OQLF).

Une étude intitulée *Je vais te me lui régler son compte : les limites de la syntaxe* par Alain Deschamps, 2015, débute par ces mots :

> *Bien que des structures comme*
> Je vais te me lui *ou* je vais te me le *+ Verbe*
> Je te me lui *ou* je te me le *+ Verbe*
> *soient unanimement rejetées par les puristes et ne figurent pas dans les grammaires du français, elles sont pourtant produites, reconnues et comprises par les locuteurs francophones même par ceux qui les refusent comme non grammaticales.*

Voir aussi ["Je vais te me les disperser" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874).

et [Certaines combinaisons de pronoms seraient interdites ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8610)

Comment: Je te leur ai donné> n'est même pas du français.

Comment: @Lambie Si, ç'en est: *Je te leur ai donné une de ces raclées.*

Comment: J'ai viens de trouver cette page (http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page173.htm) qui dis « Pour combiner un objet direct du premier plat [objets directs] avec un objet indirect du deuxième ou du quatrième plat [*lui*, *leur*], il faut se servir de la forme supplétive de l'objet indirect disjoint », suggèrant que la combinaison dont j'ai presenté n'est pas utilisée. Je pense que cette page soutient votre réponse.

Comment: Oui, cette combinaison n'est pas utilisée avec ce sens. C'est ce que j'écris dans ma réponse.

Comment: Je t'ai donné une de ces raclées/le leur est de trop. //Je ne vois pas du tout, mais pas du tout, comment tu peux dire que "Je te leur ai donné x" marche. Je leur ai donné, oui.

Comment: @Lambie Non, la phrase signifie qu'on a donné une raclée aux autres, pas à la personne à qui on s'adresse. Tout francophone natif connaît et comprend la forme *Je te leur ai donné une de ces raclées.*

Comment: Elle n'est pas enseignée donc je comprends qu'elle puisse sembler inacceptable à un non francophone.

Comment: Bien sûr, je ne dis pas le contraire: Tu parles à quelqu'un en disant: Je leur ai donné une de ces raclées. leur= d'autres personnes. Il ne s'agit pas d'enseignement, il s'agit d'écouter parler les français, dans la vie quotidienne. Tu crois que j'ai appris à parler à l'école? Plutôt 4 ans à la Sorbonne et 16 ans en France. Jamais entendu un truc pareil.

Comment: @Lambie http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2927 https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/datif_%C3%A9thique

Comment: Ah ok, je vois que la question liée avec Obélix contient déjà une réponse avec un extrait de LBU14 § 672 e), comme un auteur cité disait « ne figurent pas dans les grammaires du français ». Ça fait pas mal le tour de la question.

Comment: @némésie-t-île C'est vrai. LBU est une grammaire tellement complète qu'on peut même y trouver ce que les grammaires ne contiennent pas... ;-)

Comment: Oui, il parait que ce datif éthique s'explique dans certains cas, En tout cas, dans l'exemple pris ici, cela me semble un peu forcé. Va me ranger ta chambre, ça passe. Mais la tienne me semble toujours bizarre. D'autant plus que la "postante" dit qu'il s'agit d'une traduction....alors que là elle se trompe.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, c'est mieux, tu ne contestes plus l'existence de cette forme. Elle s'explique dans tous les cas et mon exemple n'est pas forcé. Je pourrais très bien l'avoir dit spontanément. Elle est essentiellement orale donc difficile d'en trouver des exemples écrits mais en voilà un: *Je te leur ai mis une avoinée quand ils m'ont annoncé un tarif de recherche de panne, elle est pas près d'oublier mon nom.* https://forums.audipassion.com/topic/80391-audi-compi%C3%A8gne-60/?tab=comments#comment-3019068

Comment: @Lambie Geneviève ne se trompe pas. La traduction littérale de *I gave them you* est bien *Je te leur ai donné*. Elle s'interroge, à juste titre, sur la possibilité d'une telle combinaison en français.

Comment: Mais si, elle se trompe.  La traduction litérale n'est pas une traduction. Le sens en anglais, le voici:  "I gave you (when the person was a baby or child; talking to a dog,; talking to a teenager given to a pimp, etc.) to them" is in French: *Je t'ai donné à eux*.  Dans le sens de faire cadeau de quelqu'un ou d'un animal à quelqu'un. Je te leur ai donné. Aussi bizarre en anglais qu'en français. A tel point, que tu as voulu savoir ce que cela signifie....

Comment: @Lambie Je voulais surtout savoir ce qu'**elle** entendait par là. Une traduction littérale est une traduction, pourquoi lui refuser cette qualité ? C'est comme dire qu'une réponse imparfaite n'est pas une réponse, ou une voiture qui ne démarre pas n'est pas une voiture... *I gave you* = "Je t'ai donné(e)", *I gave to them* = "Je leur ai donné". On pouvait raisonnablement penser que *I gave you to them* pouvait se traduire par "Je te leur ai donné".  Je n'ai pas d'avis sur la pertinence de *I gave you to them* en anglais, et ce n'est de toute façon pas le sujet ici.

Comment: On pouvait raisonnablement penser que I gave you to them pouvait se traduire par "Je te leur ai donné= C'est exactement ça. Rien d'autre.  Et on dirait pas litérale dans ce cas-là. C'est le seul sens **possible** de l'anglais, On dirait aussi: Je t'ai donné à eux....

Comment: @Lambie On tourne en rond. Difficile de dire que *je te leur ai donné* est le seul sens possible de l'anglais puisque cette forme n'a pas de sens en français. PS : Deux T à *li**tt**érale* (ça me rappelle quand je me suis fais corriger après avoir écrit *litteral* en anglais).

Comment: Comment dis-tu en français: I **gave my baby to them**. Je leur ai donné mon bébé. Right? Now: I gave you [as a baby] to them.  It would have to be, with pronouns: Je te leur ai donné [quand tu étais un bébé]. Right? Which is the same as: Je t'ai donné à eux [quant tu étais bébé]. You seem to not want to understand the English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124679/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).