# Pourquoi pas sers-vous?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, complément-cod

Imaginons les situations suivantes, à table avec de multiples convives:

1. mon verre est vide, mon ami a la bouteille de vin à la main, je lui demande gentiment: "sers-moi"
2. mon ami a son verre vide, je lui passe la bouteille, "sers-toi"
3. un troisième invité a son verre vide, mon ami a la bouteille à la main, "sers-le"
4. le troisième invité et moi-même avons notre verre vide, mon ami a la bouteille à la main, "sers-nous"
5. le reste de la table a son verre vide, mon ami a la bouteille à la main, "sers-les"

Et pourquoi pas:

6. le troisième invité et mon ami ont leur verre vide, mon ami a la bouteille à la main, me tournant vers les deux mais m'adressant à mon ami: "sers-vous"?

Le sens et la grammaire sont clairs, en tous cas pour moi: le sujet [tu, mon ami] sert le complément d'objet direct [vous, mon ami ainsi que le troisième invité]. Pourtant ça sonne très très mal. Pourquoi? Est-ce simplement une question d'habitude (ou plutôt d'inhabitude, si j'ose dire)? Ou bien y a-t-il une raison grammaticale cachée?

Answer (score 1):

Dans les cinq premiers exemples de la question, on tutoie la personne à qui on s'adresse.

On ne peut que tutoyer la personne à qui on dit ***sers-toi*** (<s>servez-toi</s>)

On ne peut que vouvoyer la personne à qui on dit ***servez-vous*** (<s>sers-vous</s>), ou alors, il s'agit de plusieurs personnes et là aussi, le pluriel s'impose.

On peut la tutoyer ou la vouvoyer dans les quatre autres cas:

> **sers-moi** ou **servez-moi**
> **sers-le/la** ou **servez-le/la**
> **sers-nous** ou **servez-nous**
> **sers-les** ou **servez-les**

***Vous*** s'impose bien sûr ici aussi si on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes.

Si on s'adresse à une personne qu'on tutoie et qu'on lui demande de se servir ainsi que d'autres personnes, *<s>sers-vous</s>* n'est pas utilisé bien que logiquement valide, ce sera quelque chose comme ***sers-toi et sers-les***.

On trouve quand même de très rares occurrences comme celle-ci:

> [...]tu avais remarqué son air contrarié quand elle avait vu la bouteille vide au matin et tu as pris exactement la même -, **tu vous sers** deux petits verres, Marianne pleure sur ton épaule, il y a quinze ans elle avait un mari, une galerie dans Soho exposait son travail[...]
>
> Catherine Cusset, *L'autre qu'on adorait*, 2016

Voir aussi: [Certaines combinaisons de pronoms seraient interdites ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8610/certaines-combinaisons-de-pronoms-seraient-interdites)

Comment: Euh, oui, enfin, ça ne répond pas à la question! "On ne peut que vouvoyer la personne à qui on dit servez-vous": c'est bien là tout le sens de ma question. Pourquoi?

Comment: Le thread en lien est toutefois utile et semble pour le coup plaider "en ma faveur", au sens où le sers-vous semble grammaticalement et sémantiquement correct, au même titre que le "vous t'avez donc choisi" mentionné ci-dedans.

Comment: Oui, je n'avais tout de suite compris que la question portait sur ce point particulier. On est dans le cas de **tu vous sers** qui est inusité bien que logiquement valide. Il n'y a pas de raison grammaticale cachée pour l'interdire. J'en ai trouvé une occurrence.

Comment: Puis-je te demander une référence ? Par ailleurs ton commentaire vient de me faire remarquer que la forme interrogative est bien moins choquante que l'impérative: "Tu vous sers? Merci." Bizarre.

Comment: La référence est ajoutée à ma réponse. Ce qui choque l'oreille est que dans les autres cas, on est soit dans un cas d'utilisation pronominale réfléchie (je me sers, tu te sers, vous vous servez,...) soit dans un cas de pronom personnel COD (je te sers, tu le sers, vous nous servez) mais avec *tu vous sers*, le rôle du pronom est ambigu, à cheval entre les deux.